# Event Log - MsiInstaller events' description cannot be found since last week

Tags: windows-event-log, msi, eventviewer

Since last week, machines in my network are not properly recording events from MsiInstaller. For instance:

> The description for Event ID ( 11724 ) in Source ( MsiInstaller ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: Product: Java Auto Updater -- Removal completed successfully., (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), , .

Machines having this issue have the following Registry key "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Eventlog\Application\MsiInstaller" set to:

> "%SystemRoot%\system32\msimsg.dll"

While on machines that don't exhibit this behavior, the value is:

> "C:\windows\system32\msi.dll"

Manually fixing the key's value fixes the issue and messages from MsiInstaller are successfully recorded with all details. However, I would like to understand what could have caused this. Any hints?

Comment: Have you installed or uninstalled any language packs or versions lately? Including .NET runtime versions? msimsg.dll looks like some sort of localized message resource file.